# Windows - 8(Enterprise Edition) dos prompt (cmd) throws the error like ('C:\Program' not found)

Tags: node.js, git, cmd, npm, windows-8

When i run the **cmd** in run command (or) open the command promt, i execute some npm command means it throws the error like below

**C:\Users\sivaprabug>npm**

**Skipping command-line 'C:\Program Files\Git\git-cmd.exe /K'**

**('C:\Program' not found)**

**Need a valid command-line; Edit the string resources accordingly**

FYI:-

Kindly find the attachment

[image: Error in Terminal/cmd]

Comment: That error message means that somewhere a program is trying to figure out from a full command line with arguments what the filename of the program to execute is, and is failing. Perhaps it is missing some quotes somewhere? The program that is failing is finding the space and assuming that everything before the space is the program path and filename, and everything after the space is arguments to the program.

Comment: Windows command prompt (`cmd`) is *not* **MS-DOS**! Anyway, put quotation marks around arguments with white-spaces or some other special characters in them...

Answer (score 1):

Some how the default shell has changed to git-cmd.exe
It need to restored to default.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue because the Windows environment variable wrongly given.

FYI:

How to change the environment variably

[image]